# How to include a custom library using run script xcode

Tags: xcode, run-script

I've created a library and I want to include using run script instead of manually including the .a and .h file. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

that will fail. the compiler needs atleast the h files in compilation.

for the archive you could.. in theory call `ld` manually but that isnt good at all as the compiler wont see the a file and might give you errors about missing symbols